# Godot. How to change C# version at Mono project on more actual?

Tags: c#, mono, godot

I have a Godot Mono project with .csproj file that contains:

```
<Project Sdk="Godot.NET.Sdk/3.3.0">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Could i change C# version on more actual from C# 7.3?

Comment: If you choose .NET Framework as target, then C# 7.3 is the highest supported version you can go to.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I didn't choose that. I don't know could i change framework for example or mono supportes only this.